# Statistical technique for data when three interventions are administrated and multiple responses measuring different constructs are measured

Tags: multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, manova, feature-engineering

I have a data where three interventions were administrated on subjects and different response variables (say 15 variables) on Likert Scale were observed. These response variables measure three different constructs (e.g. first five variables measure first construct (trait), next five variables measure second construct and similarly last five variables measure third construct). Assuming normality (although not prevail here), I did Multivariate Analysis of Variance (MANOVA) and performed contrasts on treatment side and response variables (trait) side. I'm also thinking Factor Analysis might be another candidate for this data.

### Questions

1. Is MANOVA appropriate here?
2. Is Factor Analysis good technique to be used here?
3. I would like to know if any other appropriate technique is available for such data sets. If so and hint for `R` package to implement that technique.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In order to be able to answer there questions one needs to know exactly what your research hypothesis is. What do you want to find out / to test / to estimate?